# How to Hide last click (add) button when click on add and when user click on remove button then show previous hide (add) button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I make a feilds where user can add test. this is all run smoothly i just want when user click on (add another test) then previous (add another test) remove and this show in new field.

all running well only issue is that click on (add another field) previous add another field not hide and also i want when user click on (remove) previous hide add another field show automatticaly.

Please check my code thanks.

```
   ! function(a) {
   "use strict";
    a(function() {
    var b = a(".wpcf7-field-groups");
    b.length && (b.each(function() {
        a(this).data("group-model", a(this).find(".wpcf7-field-group").eq(0).clone())
    }), a("body").on("wpcf7-field-groups/change", ".wpcf7-field-groups", function() {
        var b = a(this).find(".wpcf7-field-group");
        b.each(function(b) {
            a(this).find(".wpcf7-field-group-remove").toggle(b > 0);

            var c = b + 1;
            a(this).find("[name]").each(function() {
                var b = a(this),
                    d = b.closest(".wpcf7-form-control-wrap"),
                    e = b.attr("name"),
                    f = e.indexOf("[]") > -1,
                    g = e.replace("[]", ""),
                    h = g.replace(/__[0-9]*/, "") + "__" + c;
                d.length && !d.hasClass(h) && d.removeClass(g).addClass(h), h += f ? "[]" : "", b.attr("name", h)
            })
        }), a(this).find(".wpcf7-field-group-count").val(b.length)
    }), b.trigger("wpcf7-field-groups/change"), a("body").on("click", ".wpcf7-field-group-add, .wpcf7-field-group-remove", function() {
        var b = a(this),
            c = b.closest(".wpcf7-field-groups");
        if (b.hasClass("wpcf7-field-group-add")) {

            var d = c.data("group-model").clone();
            c.append(d), b.trigger("wpcf7-field-groups/added");
        } else b.trigger("wpcf7-field-groups/removed"), b.closest(".wpcf7-field-group").remove();





        return c.trigger("wpcf7-field-groups/change"), !1
    }))
})
 }(jQuery);
```

This is my full working codepen code please check and tell me how to fix this :)

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZqwORX

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

just add this to your function where you bind the click to your element:

```
 e.currentTarget.style.display = "none";
```

And send `e` as a parameter for the function.

Something like this:

```
if (b.hasClass("wpcf7-field-group-add")) {
        e.currentTarget.style.display = "none"; //ADD THIS LINE
        var d = c.data("group-model").clone();
        c.append(d), b.trigger("wpcf7-field-groups/added");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer i didn't where i did this will you please make this on my script thanks :)

Comment: Will you please add this on my above script thanks @oma

Comment: Hmm.. your code here is different from the sandbox :|

Comment: But you just need to add that line of code, and the `e` to your function...

Comment: i did this but nothing work please check this link :-https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZqwORX

Comment: will you please make this perfect over my code check my link please. Thanks https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZqwORX

Comment: Thanks your one step done now i want  when user click on remove button then show add button on div current show thanks